# Mysql Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user. While installing Drupal 7 in localhost

Tags: apache2, mysql, xampp, drupal

I recently did a clean upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04. I could easily install drupal 7 in ubuntu 14.04 but my problem is arising when i am creating a new database for drupal 7.43. I followed instruction from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-drupal-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server-with-apache).

I created a database called drupal

```
CREATE DATABASE drupal;
```

created a user called drupaluser

```
CREATE USER drupaluser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

granted the user all the privilages to the database

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,INDEX,ALTER,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,LOCK TABLES ON drupal.* TO drupaluser@localhost;
```

Flushed the privileges as per the blog

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and exited

I went to localhost/drupal and drupal began the installation process, When i reached the database section i got the following error Message from mysql

"Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'drupaluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)."

i have installed xampp 7.0.5 which works well but phpmyadmin is not working so i have decided to take this route but i am stuck

Please adivce.

Comment: I noticed that you create `drupaluser@localhost` and grant access to `user@localhost`. Probably just a typo since mysql would complain, but nevertheless....

Comment: I corrected it but i still  get the same error msg.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this command:
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,CREATE,DROP,INDEX,ALTER,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES,LOCK TABLES ON drupal.* TO 'drupaluser'@'localhost';

For more info, refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).
Link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: I tried but didn't work. I am getting the same error message and i cant access the webpage you suggested via the link.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is xampp has created a blank password for the root MySQL database.
If you leave the password field empty you should be good to go.